# enemy destruction slick2d

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm currently working on a sort of platformer in java using Slick2D and the way I currently have it set up, enemies are Enemy objects in an ArrayList. The player can shoot little circles (also held in an ArrayList) at them and if they connect, what should happen is that the enemy "dies". This is where I run into trouble. How do I get rid of an object like that? I've tried removing them from the array in a for each loop, but that throws an exception due to the fact that it is still searching said array (I think).

```
for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
  for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
    if (bullet.intersects(enemy) {
      bullets.remove(bullet);
      enemies.remove(enemies);
    }
  }
}
```

That didn't work, so now I'm trying to make an array of the indexes of the bullets and enemies interacting and then deleting them after the loop, as in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
  for (int z = 0; z < enemies.size(); z++) {
    if (bullets.get(i).intersects(enemies.get(z).getPoly())) {
      bRemove.add(i);
      eRemove.add(z);
    }
  }
}

for (Integer i : bRemove) {
  bullets.remove(i);
}

for (Integer i : eRemove) {
  enemies.remove(i);
}
```

Now it seems like nothing is happening at all. Does anyone know what I should do? This is the entirety of the main class:

```
package ca.wmc.BasicPlatform;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.newdawn.slick.Animation;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Circle;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet;
import org.newdawn.slick.geom.Polygon;

public class Game extends BasicGame  {

Player quote;
public BlockMap map;
private boolean start;
private int startCount;
private boolean lost;
private int lostCount;
private int hpTime = 0;
private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;
private ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
private int reload = 0;
private final double a = 2;
private int t = 0;

public Game() {
    super("Super Simple Platform");
}

public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    container.setVSync(true);
    container.setTargetFrameRate(60);
    map = new BlockMap("tiled/newmap.tmx");
    quote = new Player("tiled/Quote.gif", 320, 320, 3, -8);
    enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    enemies.add(new Enemy("tiled/King.gif", 50, 0, -8, 26, 32));
    enemies.add(new Enemy("tiled/Quote.gif", 200, 150, -8, 28, 32));
    start = false;
    lost = false;
    bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
}

public void update(GameContainer container, int delta) throws SlickException {
    if (!start) {
        if (container.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_Z)) {
            start = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (!lost) {

            ArrayList<Integer> eRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> bRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            quote.update(container, a, t, delta);
            for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
                enemy.update(quote, a, t);
            }

            if (t == 5) {
                t = 0;
            } else {
                t++;
            }

            if (container.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_X) && reload == 0) {
                if (quote.getCurAnimation() == quote.right()) {
                    bullets.add(new Bullet(quote.getXPos() + 28, quote.getYPos() + (int)(20 * Math.random() - 22) + 25, "r"));
                } else {
                    bullets.add(new Bullet(quote.getXPos() + 28, quote.getYPos() + (int)(20 * Math.random() - 22) + 25, "l"));
                }
                reload = 10;
            }

            if (reload > 0) {
                reload--;
            }

            for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
                if (bullet.getDirection()) {
                    bullet.setCenterX(bullet.getCenterX() + 10);
                } else { 
                    bullet.setCenterX(bullet.getCenterX() - 10);
                }
            }

            for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
                if (quote.getPoly().intersects(enemy.getPoly()) && hpTime > 50 && quote.getHP() != 0) {
                    quote.setHP(quote.getHP() - 1);
                    hpTime = 0;
                    if (quote.getHP() <= 0) {
                        lost = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            hpTime++;

            if (startCount <= 100) {
                startCount++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < enemies.size(); z++) {
                    if (bullets.get(i).intersects(enemies.get(z).getPoly())) {
                        bRemove.add(i);
                        eRemove.add(z);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (Integer i : bRemove) {
                bullets.remove(i);
            }

            for (Integer i : eRemove) {
                enemies.remove(i);
            }
        }

        if (quote.getYPos() > 640) {
            lost = true;
        }

    }
}

public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
    g.drawImage(new Image("apsci.jpg"), 0, 0);
    BlockMap.tmap.render(0, 0);
    g.drawAnimation(quote.getCurAnimation(), quote.getXPos(), quote.getYPos());
    for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
        g.drawAnimation(enemy.getCurAnimation(), enemy.getXPos(), enemy.getYPos());
    }

    for (Circle bullet : bullets) {
        g.draw(bullet);
    }

    g.drawString("HP: " + quote.getHP(), 10, 450);

    if (!start) {
        g.drawString(getTitle(), 150, 0);
        g.drawString("Controls: arrow keys to move, Z to jump, X to fire.", 150, 50);
        g.drawString("Defeat the evil.          Press Z to start.", 150, 100);
    }

    if (startCount < 100) {
        for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
            g.drawString("The Evil -->", enemy.getXPos() - 125, enemy.getYPos() + 10 + (int)(2 * Math.random()));
        }
        g.drawString("<-- You", quote.getXPos() + 50, quote.getYPos() + 10 + (int)(2 * Math.random()));
    }

    if (lost) {
        g.drawString("You have lost.", 200, 210);
    }
    if (lostCount > 150) {
        g.drawString("Game over.", 200, 260);
    }
    if (lostCount > 200) {
        g.drawString("If that wasn't already obvious.", 200, 310);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new Game(), 640, 480, false);
        app.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: _that didn't work_; what happened actually? be specific.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, you cannot modify something utilizing a for-each loop and continue iterating over. Instead, you'll need to utilize an `Iterator`: [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Since removal in an `ArrayList` also requires every object after the removed object to be shifted left by one index (hence is an `O(n)` operation), I'd suggest you might also want to look into using a `LinkedList` instead.

With regards to style, you should also always refer to `Collection` objects via their interface, not their implementation. That is,

```
ArrayList<Integer> eRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

should be

```
List<Integer> eRemove = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This way, if you do decide to change to a LinkedList, you need only change the code to:

```
List<Integer> eRemove = new LinkedList<Integer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, attempting to remove an element from an ArrayList that you are currently iterating through is bound to cause problems.

Are you sure your 'intersect' code is working?  The replacement method appears, on a quick look, to be what you need.  If it isn't doing anything, perhaps it isn't finding intersections when it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should remove at least the first bullet and first enemy correctly. If it does not, there is a problem with `intersects` method.

When first bullet is removed, all elements after it will shift so you will remove wrong bullets.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
        boolean hit = false;
        for (int z = 0; z < enemies.size(); z++) {

            if (bullets.get(i).intersects(enemies.get(z).getPoly())) {
                hit = true;
                enemies.remove(z);
                z--;
            }
        }

        if (hit) {
            bullets.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
}
```

And you should worry about ArrayList vs LinkedList perfomance until you have thousands of bullets and enemies.